# Why Android hardware-back-button closes Ionic V3 base page (tab controller) when pressed on parent-page?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm working with Ionic 3.

Android hardware back-button works nice in most situations - but when pressed on the parent page (init page) it closes/hides the app (as it is supposed to do) but it also seems to "close the app" - which causes app to load the whole system again when opened again.

If I hide the app by pressing home-button or open another app by pressing switch-app-button and then open my Ionic app again it opens immediately - but if my app is closed with back-button it will show Splash Screen again and loads the whole app again.

Is there any solution to modify hw-back-button action only to hide the app and not to close the tab-navigation-base-page?

Answer (score 0):

YOu should be able to override the NavBack Button Take a look at this

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/5071

there are a few workaround people have implemented. Look at Tomsun's post.

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/5071#issuecomment-179789428

Comment: I'll check this out... but it seems you've provieded information about how to handle with this situation with ionic-v1 or ionic-v2. Ionic-V3 is not the same and has changed much...

Comment: Oh sorry about that.